# How to add more polygons in edit mode

Tags: modeling

How to add more polygons in edit mode without using any modifier or subdivision.[image]

Comment: You could add more polygons without Subsurf but that would be generally the same - subdividing mesh. If you want to subdivide only part of mesh you'll need to track the topology, this blog is useful for that - http://topology-guides.tumblr.com.

Comment: Not sure why you exclude subdivision, because this is often a good way to add polygons.

Comment: It is not clear, why you want to add polygons? If you want to make the resolution higher, then there are not many rational alternatives (than subdividing).

Answer (score 4):

There are several approaches to 'add' more polygons

**Subdividing**

You can open the menu 'specials' by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> while beeing in edit-mode, where you can find 'Subdivide' and 'Subdivide Smooth'.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html

Note: In the Toolbar (toggle with <kbd>T</kbd>) options will be displayed.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to cut edges. This will add more polygons.
https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html

**Mesh adding**

By pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> you can open up the mesh-menu, where you can select and insert a mesh.

**Extruding**

By pressing <kbd>E</kbd> you can extrude your selected vertices, edges or faces.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html

There are multiple extrude-modes that you can find pressing <kbd>space</kbd> and tiping 'extrude'. That will display all actions with 'extrude' in their name.

**Insetting**

By pressing <kbd>I</kbd> Takes the currently selected faces and creates an inset of them, with adjustable thickness and depth. If several faces are selected you can choose to inset them individually.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset

**Knife Tool**

By pressing <kbd>K</kbd> you can open the 'Knife Tool' where you can cut faces, what will create more polygons.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?highlight=knife

**Joining**

Although this can't be made in edit-mode. In Object mode select multiple meshes and join them pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: "Joining" does not fit the questioner ' criteria of "more polygons" and "edit mode; otherwise, good answer.

Comment: I just realised that the questioner didn't also want subdivision, but I keep it, because it might be helpful to others. :)

Comment: Using J in edit mode will indeed create new polygons

Answer (score 0):

- Loop Cut and Slide .... with Control-R

[image]

- Offset Edge Slide ....  with Shift-Control-R

[image]

- Intersect Knife and Intersect Boolean

[image]

- Duplicate Mesh
- Bevel

Modifiers

- Boolean Modifier, Intersect, Add, Difference
- Remesh Modifier and possibly Apply